# Implement error in postfix conversion (python)

Tags: python, stack, postfix-notation

I need to input code to produce an error for incorrect output. The code runs the way it should and produces the correct postfix result, but needs an error for incorrect input.

```
def postfix(expr):
    '''
    >>> postfix('2 *    5   +   3    ^ -2       +1  +4')
    'error message'
    >>> postfix('2    5')
    'error message'
    >>> postfix('25 +')
    'error message'
    >>> postfix('   2 *  (  5   +   3)    ^ 2+(1  +4    ')
    'error message'
    >>> postfix('   2 *  (  5   +   3)    ^ 2+)1  +4(    ')
    'error message'
    '''
    if len(expr)<=0 or not isinstance(expr,str): 
        print("expr error: postfix")
        return "error"


    postFix = " "
    stack = Stack()
    #skip the spaces
    for ch in expr:
        if (ch == " "):
            continue

        if isOper(ch):
            postFix += ch

        elif ch.isnumeric():
            postFix += format(float(ch), '.1f')+' '

        else:
            if isleftParent(ch):
                stack.push(ch)
         #right       
            elif isrightParent(ch):
                operation = stack.pop()

                while not isleftParent(operation):
                    postFix += operation
                    operation = stack.pop()

            else:
                while (not stack.isEmpty()) and priorityLessEqual(ch, stack.peek()):
                    postFix += stack.pop()
                stack.push(ch)

    while(not stack.isEmpty()):
        postFix += stack.pop()

    return str(postFix)
```

Comment: Can you show us how `Stack()` looks like

Comment: So what's your question?